# Creating models and DBTable under library directory and mapping it for using Models and DBTables

Tags: zend-framework

Running zf create project command has created a project with common directory structure. 
Now I want to customize it, like, I want to have the Models and DBTable directories separately and that too under library directory. In that case, I want to know how to refer the class name and how to create namespace to refer,related to the Models and DBTable created under Library directory. I can give more details if required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting models in library directory in Zend Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226419/putting-models-in-library-directory-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a separate directory in your library (for instance Example/), you have to add the namespace to the application.ini:
`autoloadernamespaces[] = "Example_"`

This will tell the autoloader to look for the files in the include path when the class name starts with Example_.